# How to get the related JIRAISSUEKEY of given changeset ID using FishEye REST API request or EyeQL or Anyother possible way?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, fisheye, atlassian-fisheye, eyeql

Inputs in Hand:-

1. ChangesetID (csid)
2. Repository Name
3. Branch Name

Requirement to find:

1. Get the **JIRAISSUEKEY** releated to given changesetid.

I was searching in EyeQL & FishEye REST API but couldn't find any possible ways to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Below URL helps to get the JIRAISSUEKEY of a changesetId.

```
   http://hg.domain.com/log/<repo_name>/rev/branch(<branch_name>)%20and%20<csid>
```